# How can I post multiple survey responses using survey monkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

I have posted a survey response to survey monkey like this and the response saved in survey monkey.

```
POST https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/{collector_id}/responses

json = {
  "custom_variables": {
    "custvar_1": "one",
    "custvar_2": "two"
  },
  "response_status": "completed",
  "custom_value": "custom identifier for the response",
  "date_created": "2015-10-06T12:56:55+00:00",
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "recipient_id": "564728340",
{
  "pages": [{
    "id": "12345678",
    "questions": [
    {
        "answers": [{
            "choice_id": "12345678"
        }],
        "id": "12345678"
    },
    {
        "answers": [{
            "row_id": "12345678",
            "col_id": "12345678",
            "choice_id": "12345678"
        }],
        "id": "12345678"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to post multiple responses in a signle API call. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to bulk import responses with the SurveyMonkey API.

This is something that will likely be available in the future but there isn't a current ETA.

Comment: I am using survey monkey API for a survey in my website. Which app should create? Private or Public?